# MALFORMED QUERY : [object Object]: Field must be grouped or aggregated: Name

Tags: soql

```
SELECT Account.Id,Account.Name,Account.Phone,Status FROM Case WHERE Status='Closed' GROUP BY Account.Id
```

It displays an error while qurying this.Anyone please help me to correct this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this SELECT Account.Id,Account.Name,Account.Phone,Status FROM Case WHERE Status='Closed' GROUP BY Account.Id,Account.Name,Account.Phone,Status;

Comment: @Marc, pls put as an answer otherwise this question will be marked as 'unanswered' forever. And you'll get some credits too :-)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have to group all the fields you select. The working version of your query would look like this:

```
 SELECT Account.Id,Account.Name,Account.Phone,Status FROM Case WHERE Status='Closed' GROUP BY Account.Id,Account.Name,Account.Phone,Status
```

For more information see the documentation here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby.htm